# Google Maps custom data layers not triggering on zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

Two part question: What is wrong with the if statment I've written (fixed), and am I using setMap(null) correctly?

I have a map where I want to show different geoJSONs depending on the zoom level. When I set the following, I get the finer scale show up on zoom, but it's just additive, not an actual change:

```
   if ($('#map').length) {

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel <= 11) {
      window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "toronto_regions.geojson" );

    }
    else {
      window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "districts.geojson" );
    }
  })
```

Now, I added an `else if` statement, just to stabilize things until it gets more complex. However, `} elseif (zoomLevel <= 9) {` objects to the `{` as an unexpected identifier, and commenting it out just passes the problem off to the `else` statement. In the meantime, I've been trying to add in a setMap method to clear out the old map data before adding in new stuff.

On clearing out the syntax issues, I am now getting the error         `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map` in association with the setMap method:

```
window.map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
window.map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

if ($('#map').length) {
  window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "cities.geojson" );
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel < 12 || zoomLevel > 9) {
      window.map.data.setMap('null');
      window.map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
      window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "cities.geojson" );
    } else if (zoomLevel <= 9) {
       window.map.data.setMap('null');
       window.map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
       window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "county.geojson" );
    } else if (zoomLevel >= 11) {
       window.map.data.setMap('null');
       window.map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
       window.map.data.loadGeoJson( "districts.geojson" );
    };
  })
```

Any input on setMap would be greatly appreciated - manipulating Google Maps is new territory for me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Could you clarify? A lot of this stuff is custom and local, and the issue is confined to this event.

Comment: Question is updated to show syntax corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors:

- `elseif` should be `else if`
- `} else (zoomLevel >= 11) {` should be  `} else if (zoomLevel >= 11) {`

I suspect you want `window.map.data.setMap`